# On non-trivial normal subgroup(s) of $A(S)$ , where $S$ is infinite

Tags: group-theory, permutations, normal-subgroups

Let $A(\mathbb R)$ be the permutation group of $\mathbb R$ , is this group simple ? In general for an infinite set $S$ , how may we determine whether $A(S)$ has any non-trivial normal subgroup or not ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $S$ is an infinite set, the group of finitary permutations on $S$, that is, those permutations that fix all but a finite number of elements, is always a non-trivial, proper normal subgroup.

See [this page](http://books.google.it/books?id=4bNj8K1omGAC&pg=PA165&lpg=PA165&dq=group%20of%20finitary%20permutations&source=bl&ots=q4jXfK05We&sig=wPRXVKkJVKMmjX_BlKBm6duSPU4&hl=en&sa=X&ei=ypwRVP2eHISyPKzbgcAH&ved=0CDwQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=group%20of%20finitary%20permutations&f=false) from Peter Cameron's *Permutation Groups* for further details. It mentions in particular the finitary alternating groups. And the bounded symmetric groups, that is, fix a cardinal number $\mathfrak{n}$ not larger than the cardinality of $S$, and consider the group of permutations that move less than $\mathfrak{n}$ points.

Comment: In fact the only nontrivial normal subgroups of ${\rm Sym}(S)$ are the groups of even finitary permutation groups, together with the subgroups whose support has cardinality less than some fixed cardinal number.