# Let $H$ be the set of all almost indentity maps $f \in G$. Show that $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups

> Let $G = S_{\Bbb N}$ the group of bijections $f : \Bbb N \to \Bbb N$ with binary operation given by composition of maps. Call $f \in G$ *almost identity* if for some $m_f \in \Bbb N$ it holds that $f(n)=n$ for all $n \ge m_f$. Let $H$ be the set of all *almost indentity* maps $f \in G$. Show that $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$.

First to show that $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ we pick $f, g \in H$. Now we have that $(fg^{-1})(n) = f(g^{-1}(n))$ and since $f \in H$ there exists $g^{-1}(x_0) \in \Bbb N$ such that $f(g^{-1}(x))=g^{-1}(x)$ for all $g^{-1}(x) \ge g^{-1}(x_0)$. So $fg^{-1} \in H$.

To show that $H$ is normal we pick $g \in G$ and $f \in H$ and since $f \in H$ there exists $g^{-1}(x_0)$ such that for all $g^{-1}(x) \ge g^{-1}(x_0)$ $f(g^{-1}(x_0))=g^{-1}(x_0)$. Thus $$(gfg^{-1})(x) = g(f(g^{-1}(x))) = g(g^{-1}(x))=x$$ for all $g^{-1}(x) \ge g^{-1}(x_0)$. So $gfg^{-1} \in H$.

Is this correct? I think they meant by composition of maps that I should consider $(f \circ g^{-1})(x)$ instead of $(f-g)(x) = f(x) - g(x)$?

Comment: You're correct about composition of maps (rather than differences). However, "since $f \in H$ there exists $g^{-1}(x_0) \in \Bbb N$ such that $f(g^{-1}(x))=g^{-1}(x)$ for all $g^{-1}(x) \ge g^{-1}(x_0)$" is not a correct application of the definition: one would have to justify why one can choose $m_f$ of the form $g^{-1}(x_0)$, and then justify why $f(g^{-1}(x))=g^{-1}(x)$ for all $g^{-1}(x) \ge g^{-1}(x_0)$. This can be done, but it's not complete currently.

Comment: Wouldn't it follow from $g^{-1}$ being a surjection? It covers all of $\Bbb N$ so why couldn't I choose $m_f$ of the form $g^{-1}(x_0)$ as it's pretty much the same thing as choosing any natural number?

Comment: What you need to show is that there is a number $n_{fg^{-1}}$ such that if $n\geq n_{fg^{-1}}$, then $fg^{-1}(n) = n$. I do not think you have written anything that looks like that. Do you?

Comment: What you call *almost identity* is usually called *finitary permutation*. The question has been answered here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/929805/how-to-show-fs-is-normal-in-syms

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I think I'm denoting $g^{-1}(x_0)$ as $n_{fg^{-1}}$?

Comment: But your conclusion reads "$f(g^{-1}(x))=g^{-1}(x)$." Note that this doesn't tell us that $fg^{-1}$ fixes $x$, and you are supposed to be proving that $fg^{-1}$ fixes all $x$ after a certain point. (And the fact that you need to include a question mark should tell you that *at best* what you have is highly confusing, if the person who wrote it isn't sure about what it says...)

Comment: Well yes! That's why I posted the question in the first place right? I see if I can try to use what you commented to come up with a better argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would reason that way.

1. $H$ is a subgroup of G. Let $f,g\in H$. Take $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $f(x)=g(x)=x$ for all $x>n$. Then $g^{-1}(x)=x$ for all $x>n$. Hence $(fg^{-1})(x)=f(g^{-1}(x))=f(x)=x$ for all $x>n$. So $fg^{-1}\in H$.
2. $H$ is a normal subgroup. Let $f\in H$, $g\in S_\mathbb{N}$. Take $n\in\mathbb{N}$  such that $f(x)=x$ for all $x>n$. Now choose $m\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $g(x)>n$ for all $x>m$. (Such $m$ exists because if for any $m$ there exists $x_m>m$ such that $g(x_m)\leq n$, then $g(\{x_m\mid m\in\mathbb{N}\})\subset\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ the latter contradicts the injectivity of $g$.)
   Then for all $x>m$ we get
   $$
   g^{-1}fg(x)=g^{-1}f(g(x))=g^{-1}(g(x))=x.
   $$
   Hence $g^{-1}fg\in H$.

Comment: What is the contradiction you're referring to?

Comment: @SleepWalker
we get a contradiction with the injectivity of $g$, see the refinement of my answer.

Comment: why does $g(\{x_m\mid m\in\mathbb{N}\})\subset\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ contradict injectivity of $g$?

Comment: @SleepWalker, on the left is an infinite set, and on the right is a finite set. An image of an infinite set under an injective mapping cannot be a finite set.